# Exception while running Camel In Action 2 - chapter7-rules - prototype

Tags: apache-camel, wildfly, redhat, wildfly-swarm

I'm getting the below exception while running the chapter7-rules from CamelInAction2 examples in github.

> [INFO] Starting .war
>   Thu Mar 07 10:15:18 CET 2019 INFO [org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap] (main) Dependencies not bundled; resolving from M2REPO.
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from
>   modules/org/wildfly/extension/camel/main/module.xml   at
>   org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder.findModule(BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder.java:85)
>     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:439)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:342)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:289)
>     at org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1230)  at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.addExportedPaths(Module.java:1278)   at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1122)   at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1449)   at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1477)  at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)  at
>   org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.getMainClass(MainInvoker.java:113)
>     at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.main(MainInvoker.java:102)
>
> Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module
>   from modules/org/wildfly/extension/camel/main/module.xml  at
>   org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:228)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder.findModule(BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder.java:61)
>     ... 11 more
>
> Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to add
>   artifact 'org.jboss.gravia:gravia-container-wildfly-extension:1.3.1'
>   (position: END_TAG seen
>   ...name="org.jboss.gravia:gravia-container-wildfly-extension:1.3.1"/>...
>   @4:79) caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty   at
>   org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseArtifact(ModuleXmlParser.java:836)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResources(ModuleXmlParser.java:739)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:535)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:340)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:226)
>     ... 12 more

Can someone please help me to resolve the issue in the work-space.

Regards, 
Abin

Comment: Smells like a corrupt zip or some download problem. Are you behind some http proxy and the internet

Comment: Thank you Claus for your reply. 
No, I'm working on my personal system and home internet.

I tried downloading the jar files manually and adding it to the local maven repository. But still no luck.